# How can I find out what changes the value in /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq?

Tags: linux, kernel, proc, magic-sysrq

For some reason the value stored in the `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` file on my system changes to 16. It happens quite frequently, like once-twice an hour but in a random moment of time.

As I understand, I can't use `inotify`, because files under `/proc` aren't actually files. So how can I find out what changes this value?

UPD:
Tried to change kernel config in /boot to have

```
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_DEFAULT_ENABLE=0x0001
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_SERIAL_SEQUENCE=""
```

And also editing /etc/sysct.conf to have

```
kernel.sysrq=1
```

And finally just `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`.

The last one helps for a bit, but later it drops to 16 again.

Comment: What value do you expect it to have? What is it changing from? Is this actually a problem? 16 is a perfectly normal value (see https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysrq.html).

Comment: 16 is normal, but not for me. I expect to have at least an OOM killer hotkey.
I tried to set it to 1 with kernel config, or by just echo > /proc/sys/kerlnel/sysrq. But it drops to 16 all the time.

Comment: So, is your kernel compiled with `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ`? According to the docs, you need to say “yes” to ‘Magic SysRq key (CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ)’ when configuring the kernel. And then of course recompile.

Comment: You should be able to use auditd,  with a rule like `auditctl -w /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq -k sysrq` to log system calls made on that file.

Comment: @LjmDullaart yes it is. And even it wasn't, it's still would be a mystery why something changes this value.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wow, it's seems like auditd works. It logs syscalls to the file, that's something. Thank you!